# Unable to format output in Python correctly

Tags: python

I am unable to format in Python correctly. Below is what my list looks like. I am not sure why the spacing is off on some of the fields. Below is my code as well as a snip of how it reads.

```
def main():

    golf_file = open('golf.txt', 'r') #open file

    first_name = golf_file.readline() #read first line
    print('First Name\tLast Name\tHandicap\tGolf Score\tOver, Under or Par') #print headings
    while first_name != '': #while statement for loop
         last_name = golf_file.readline()
         handicap = golf_file.readline()
         golf_score = golf_file.readline()


         #stripping newline from each string
         first_name = first_name.rstrip('\n')
         last_name = last_name.rstrip('\n')
         handicap = handicap.rstrip('\n')
         golf_score = golf_score.rstrip('\n')

         handicap_num = float(handicap)
         golfscore_num = int(golf_score)
         #if statement to determine if golf score is over, under or par
         if golfscore_num == 80:
            OverUnderPar = ('Par')
         elif golfscore_num < 80:
             OverUnderPar = ('Under Par')
         else:
             OverUnderPar = ('Over Par')

        #print info with two tabs for positioning.
         print( first_name, '\t''\t', last_name, '\t''\t', handicap_num, '\t', '\t', golfscore_num, '\t', '\t', OverUnderPar)


         first_name = golf_file.readline()


    golf_file.close() #close file

main()
```

---

```
First Name  Last Name   Handicap    Golf Score  Over, Under or Par
Andrew       Marks       11.2        72          Under Par
Betty        Franks          12.8        89          Over Par
Connie       William         14.6        92          Over Par
Donny        Ventura         9.9         78          Under Par
Ernie        Turner          10.1        81          Over Par
Fred         Smythe          8.1         75          Under Par
Greg         Tucker          7.2         72          Under Par
Henry        Zebulon         8.3         83          Over Par
Ian          Fleming         4.2         72          Under Par
Jan          Holden          7.7         84          Over Par
Kit          Possum          7.9         79          Under Par
Landy        Bern        10.3        93          Over Par
Mona         Docker          11.3        98          Over Par
Kevin        Niles       7.1         80          Par
Pam          Stiles          10.9        87          Over Par
Russ         Hunt        5.6         73          Under Par
```

Comment: Tabs are generally unreliable for text formatting, read about [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for a better space-based formatting

Comment: @Michael Butscher  Thank you for the response. I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

If the name is too big(over 6 char) the tab will be moved one more down. You can either check if the name is too big and move it down own tab.By using something like
`numTabs = '\t' * (2-len(last_name)//6`

Or a better approach would use something like `str.format` as mentioned by @Michael Butscher in the comments.